# Is the output of metric tensor acting on two contravariant vectors inddependent of choice of bases?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

The metric tensor lives in the (0,2) tensor space at a point. I can choose arbitrary bases in this tensor space. The metric tensor can take two tangent vectors as input and output a scalar. Let the tangent vectors be defined in an arbitrary basis set in the tangent space at the same point. Given the arbitrariness of choice of bases above, is the output scalar of the metric tensor guaranteed to be independent of the choices of bases?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can think about this action without needing bases at all: if $v,w$ are vectors and $g$ is a metric then the scalar $g(v,w)$ is well defined, since by definition a metric is a map sending two tangent vectors to a scalar (satisfying some extra conditions).

If you want to choose bases and take components so that the scalar is $\sum_{ij} g_{ij} v^i w^j,$ then the result is independent of the basis *so long as you use the same basis for all three objects*. Explicitly, this means we choose a contravariant basis $e_i$ with dual basis $\theta^i$ and calculate $$\sum_{ij} g(e_i,e_j)\theta^i(v)\theta^j(w).$$ If you change the basis, the dual nature of the transformation laws for $e_i$ and $\theta^i$ will make them cancel out perfectly.

Comment: Would the output scalar change if instead of dual bases for the tangent and cotangent spaces, I picked arbitrary bases?

Comment: @IanDsouza: if you mean that you choose unrelated bases $e_i$ and $\theta^i$ and evaluate $\sum_{ij}g(e_i,e_j)\theta^i(v)\theta^j(w),$ then yes, the result will change (and thus will not be $g(v,w)$). When using component expansions of tensor expressions, we always use the same basis (and its dual) for everything.